# Elegant and Pythonic Approach to Changing List of Objects

Tags: python, performance

I am looking for an *efficient*, pythonic way to search and change a list of objects.

The problem is simple: A coffee object has three properties: name ("Frapublabla"), color ("dark brown"), and taste ("bitter").  Each coffee has one unique name, and may have multiple colors and tastes.  Barista() supplies information about a new coffee.  Once Barista() is done supplying n coffees, the code outputs all coffees.

The obvious, iterative approach is this:

```
Define <coffee> - a class with three properties: name, color, taste.
Define coffeeList = [] , tempNameList = []

For n times:
     Get coffee name, color, taste from the user. Each time:

    Search tempNameList for the name of the coffee.
    If the coffee name is not there, then:
        Create a new coffee object, add to coffeeList.  The object includes name, color, and taste.
        Add coffee name to tempNameList.

    If the coffee name is found on tempNameList:
        Iterate through the coffeeList to find the right coffee object. Then:
            Add to that object another name or color.
```

This approach doesn't scale well.  For one, each time a coffee is added, we need to search the entire coffeeList, fetching the properties of each object.

Is there a more pythonic and elegant way to solve this?  collections.defaultdict() was the closest I got, but doesn't seem applicable to this problem.

Comment: `coffees = {name : {colors : [], tastes : []}` A nested dictionary like that comes to mind

Comment: As stated above, nested dicts will work nicely, as will defaultdicts. Python dictionaries support constant average time lookup, so there isn't much need to worry about scalability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defaultdicts is definitely the way to go on this one, although, my personal preference would be to avoid nested dictionaries IF you are trying to take an object-oriented approach to solving the problem.  Here is one potential pythonic solution.

```
import collections

class Coffee():
    def __init__(self, name='', color='', taste=''):
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
        self.taste = taste

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0} {1} {2}'.format(self.name, self.color, self.taste)

prompt = "Enter name,color,taste or ctrl-d when done: "
coffees = collections.defaultdict(Coffee)

while True:
    try:
        name, color, taste = input(prompt).split(',')
        coffees[name].name = name
        coffees[name].color = color
        coffees[name].taste = taste
    except ValueError:
        print("Try again!")
    except EOFError:
        print()
        break


print(coffees)
```

~

Comment: I'll try this one and do some time comparisons vs the other approaches.  I personally also prefer an OO approach.  I'll post my results here tomorrow morning.

Comment: @mdadm: this solution overwrites the color and taste, each time a coffee with the same name is entered. The OP states, that these attributes should be added to the coffee-object with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the three different approaches to this, as suggested below by @Cyber, @jme, and @mdadm: (1) object-oriented using collections.defaultdict and (2) regular dict, and (3) nested dict.  The timing results are pretty much the same.  I cannot answer for memory usage and other CPU measurements.  I'm going with #1 because of readability and the OO nature.

Here are the results, in seconds.  Each "try" iterates the code 1M times.  There are 20 randomly-generated Coffee Names, and each Coffee gets 10 Tastes and 10 Colors:

```
Try| Approach 1 | App 2 | App 3 |
+--+------------+-------|-------|
| 1|    41.1    | 42.1  | 42.1  |
| 2|    39.1    | 41.2  | 41.6  |
| 3|    38.6    | 41.1  | 40.1  |
| 4|    40.9    | 42.5  | 41.3  |
| 5|    39.5    | 40.1  | 39.7  |
```

The code is below.

**Approach 1:**

```
import collections, random, time

class Coffee():
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = name
        self.color = set([])
        self.taste = set([])

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0} {1} {2}'.format(self.name, self.color, self.taste)

startTime = time.clock()

coffees = collections.defaultdict(Coffee)

for counter in range(1000000):

    name = "Name_" + str(random.randint(1, 20))
    taste = "taste_" + str(random.randint(1, 10))
    color = "color_" + str(random.randint(1, 10))

    coffees[name].name = name
    coffees[name].taste.add(taste)
    coffees[name].color.add(color)

print (time.clock() - startTime)
```

**Approach 2:**

```
import random, time

class Coffee():
    def __init__(self, name, color, taste):
        self.name = name
        self.color = set([])
        self.taste = set([])

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{0} {1} {2}'.format(self.name, self.color, self.taste)

startTime = time.clock()

coffeeList = {}

for counter in range(1000000):

    name = "Name_" + str(random.randint(1, 20))
    color = "color_" + str(random.randint(1, 10))
    taste = "taste_" + str(random.randint(1, 10))

    if name not in coffeeList:
        coffeeObj = Coffee(name, color, taste)
        coffeeList[name] = coffeeObj
    else:
        coffeeList[name].color.add(color)
        coffeeList[name].taste.add(taste)

print (time.clock() - startTime)
```

**Approach 3:**

```
import random, time

coffeeNestedDict = {}

startTime = time.clock()

for counter in range(1000000):

    name = "Name_" + str(random.randint(1, 20))
    color = "color_" + str(random.randint(1, 10))
    taste = "taste_" + str(random.randint(1, 10))

    if name not in coffeeNestedDict:
        coffeeNestedDict[name] = {"Color" : set([color]), "Taste" : set([taste])}

    else:
        coffeeNestedDict[name]["Color"].add(color)
        coffeeNestedDict[name]["Taste"].add(taste)

print (time.clock() - startTime)
```